# How dealing with semi-similar rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i want to average `price` based on similar `family` and `city` columns in different rows, suppose i have following dataframe,

```
df1 = [ID, name, family, city, price
        1,    a,      g,    u,    25
        2,    f,      b,    c,    20
        3,    i,      b,    c,    15
        4,    k,      b,    c,    10
        5,    r,      b,    c,    15
        6,    d,      r,    t,    20
        7,    q,      x,    s,    11]
```

My expected dataframe is:

```
df1 = [ID, name, family, city, price
        1,    a,      g,    u,    25
        2,    f,      b,    c,    15
        3,    i,      b,    c,    15
        4,    k,      b,    c,    15
        5,    r,      b,    c,    15
        6,    d,      r,    t,    20
        7,    q,      x,    s,    11]
```

and i used `groupby` but it doesn't work well,

```
shareg1 = df1[['ID','name','family','city','price']].groupby(['family','city']).mean().reset_index()`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the usual trick

```
df1['avg_price']= df1[['ID','name','family','city','price']].groupby(['family','city']).price.transform('mean')
```

Comment: `df['avg_price'] = df.groupby(['family','city'])['price'].transform('mean')`